# creating a substring of three from a string "welcome"

Tags: java, substring

I'm new to the Java world and I came across a problem. Please have a look and help me in this case.

I have taken a string as "welcome" and I need to store the substrings of 3.
And I'm expecting the elements as "wel", "elc", "lco", "com", "ome", "mew", "ewe".

And I'm getting the output as
wel
elc
lco
com
ome
null
null

I didn't understand how to iterate for the last two elements.

```
String string = "welcome";
String stringArray[] = new String[string.length()];
for (int j = 0; j < string.length() - 2; j++) {
    stringArray[j] = string.substring(j, j + 3);
}

for (String d : stringArray)
    System.out.println(d);
```

I have tried this. Can anyone please help in this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot archieve that using `substring()` method, because `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` yields only characters that are in range of <beginIndex; endIndex). So the `endIndex` must be greater then `beginIndex`.

For example
`"welcome".substring(3,6);` would yield "com", because "c" is at index "3" of "welcome" string (remember that we are counting from "0"), and the "m" is **before** the index "6" (because the `endIndex` is exclusive, as the docs says):

```
Params:
beginIndex – the beginning index, inclusive. 
endIndex – the ending index, exclusive.
```

Instead, you should travel letter by letter and collect the letters using modulo operation. For example like this:

```java
String string = "welcome";
int substringLength = 3;
String[] stringArray = new String[string.length()];

for (int j = 0; j < string.length(); j++) {
    StringBuilder substringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < substringLength; i++) {
        substringBuilder.append(string.charAt((j + i) % string.length()));
    }
    stringArray[j] = substringBuilder.toString();
}

for (String d : stringArray) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this code  will be easier to understand.

```java
        String str = "welcome";
        String concatStr = str + str;
        String[] strArr = new String[str.length()];
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            strArr[j] = concatStr.substring(j, j + 3);
        }

        for (String d : strArr)
            System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Seems clunky to create the concatStr, but given OP is clearly doing a homework assignment I'm sure this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your for loop needs to iterate exactly `string.length()` times, so `j < string.length() - 2` is too few iterations.

However, there's a number of ways to achieve this.

- You could copy the beginning of the string to the end of it, so you can easily just use `substring(j, j + 3)`:

  ```java
  String ss = string + string.substring(0, 3);
  String[] stringArray = new String[string.length()];
  for (int j = 0; j < string.length(); j++) {
      stringArray[j] = ss.substring(j, j + 3);
  }
  ```
- You could also add a portion of the beginning of the string if you are almost at the end:

  ```java
  String[] stringArray = new String[string.length()];
  for (int j = 0; j < string.length(); j++) {
      String result = string.substring(j, Math.min(j + 3, string.length()));
      if (j + 3 >= string.length()) {
          result += string.substring(0, j + 3 - string.length());
      }
      stringArray[j] = result;
  }
  ```